# Atom Editor: Soft-wrap like sublimetext in Atom

Tags: sublimetext, text-editor, atom-editor

Why Atom can't soft-wrap code like sublime text?
I want full screen code but soft-wrap. that means the end of line and close minimap cut line.
How i can do that in atom?

[image]

Answer (score 29):

There are a few settings that can affect soft wrapping in Atom. They are all in the Settings view, accessed by pressing <kbd>⌘,</kbd> (command+comma) if you're using the default keybinds on OS X.

First, to enable soft wrapping, check the "Soft Wrap" checkbox. This will enable soft wrapping at the edge of the window:

[image: Soft Wrapping at Edge]

If you want to soft wrap at the line down the right side of the editor, check the "Soft Wrap At Preferred Line Length" checkbox:

[image: Soft Wrapping at Preferred Line Length]

The line indicates your preferred line length, and you can change its position by editing the number under "Preferred Line Length," which affects wrapping with the above option enabled:

[image: Wrapping with New Preferred Line Length]

Finally, if you want the wrapped lines to be indented a bit, you can set a value in the "Soft Wrap Hanging Indent" option:

[image: Soft Wrap Hanging Indent]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you also add how I can add a keyboard shortcut to **toogle soft wrap** in Atom. I have been trying to do that for some time now, but no luck. I want to assign the key `alt + z` to atom for toggling soft wrap.

Comment: @PromisePreston add this to your `keymap.cson`:  `'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-z': 'editor:toggle-soft-wrap'` (see [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5962))

Comment: Plus 1 for Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the file in your atom editor, there you can see settings option.
2. click on the settings option or you can use the shortcut control+comma(ctrl+,).
3. Then click on the editor tab.
4. scroll down below and you get the option called soft wrap.
5. click on the soft wrap option .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I think it can help others also.

The number is: 99999999999999999999 (i think we can add 2 more 9-s to it)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your keymap.cson: [Reference](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5962)

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'f10': 'editor:toggle-soft-wrap'
```

Second Method

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Open config.cson.  Edit>Open Your Config.

```
  editor:
    softWrap: true
```